# Looking for DMS Software with Thumbnail, IMAP Support

Tags: document-management

I am looking for a DMS software.  I have been searching whole year but could not find that satisfies my needs. I have even considering to write it myself but this is last thing.

I am looking for DMS with following features:

- It should run on Windows and locally, not remote
- It should generate thumbnails from all my documents and by search able to show them
- It should also be able to scan all my IMAP accounts; there are many PDF documents attached
- Should be able to tag the documents

Does not need to be necessarily free or open-source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should the DMS permanently keep track of what documents have been recently deleted/added to the IMAP accounts? Or is it acceptable if the DMS copies the documents from the IMAP accounts as a one-shot operation?

Comment: for me does not matter really, if i have found something either way is good.